# Getting C# to talk Twitter. (C# new user question. Scope?)

Tags: c#, twitter

In trying to implement the Twitter code at http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681 I am getting a compile time error:

> The name “apiResponse does not exist in the current context”,

Usually I would fix a problem of this type by fully qualifying the call, for example instead of saying:

```
Response.Redirect(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
```

I would instead say:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
```

The problem is, I have no idea what to do with the apiResponse problem. Any ideas?

Here is the relevant code file:

```
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Configuration;  
using System.Collections;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.Security;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;  
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;  
using System.Net;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Collections.Specialized;    
namespace ArduinoSerialCommTest  
{  
    class Tweet  
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            string url = "";
            string xml = "";
            oAuthTwitter oAuth = new oAuthTwitter();

            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["oauth_token"] == null)
            {
                //Redirect the user to Twitter for authorization.
                //Using oauth_callback for local testing.
                oAuth.CallBackUrl = "http://localhost";
               System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
            }
            else
            {
                //Get the access token and secret.
                oAuth.AccessTokenGet(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["oauth_token"], System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["oauth_verifier"]);
                if (oAuth.TokenSecret.Length > 0)
                {
                    //We now have the credentials, so make a call to the Twitter API.
                    url = "http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.xml";
                    xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
                    apiResponse.InnerHtml = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(xml);

                    //POST Test
                    //url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml";
                    //xml = oAuth.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.POST, url, "status=" + oAuth.UrlEncode("Hello @swhitley - Testing the .NET oAuth API"));
                    //apiResponse.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlEncode(xml);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apiResponse` is a server side div in a `aspx` page. Please check again. If you do not have any div there, put the following there.

```
<div id="apiResponse" runat="server"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to implement this as a desktop app (Windows forms app). Does that change things?

Comment: yes, you would need to use `PinCode` for making it work on desktop apps.

Comment: here is the link for sample of desktop app integration with twitter. http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=856

Comment: please mark it as answered if this have helped you. thanks. :)